# How to set TargetId (possibly function name) for a scheduled event rule from Serverless.yaml

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I need to set a target id to the rule. As of now the targetId is testLambdaSchedule but I want to have it set to a custom Id.

Please let me know if there is a way to do that.

```
functions:
  testLambda:
    handler: handler.testingingLambda
    timeout: 300
    events:
      - schedule:
          name: newestTestRule
          rate: cron(0 12 5 4 ? 2005)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
functions:
  testLambdaModified:
    handler: handler.testingingLambda
    timeout: 300
    events:
      - schedule:
          name: newestTestRule
          rate: cron(0 12 5 4 ? 2005)
resources:
  Resources:
    TestLambdaModifiedEventsRuleSchedule1: # it is  {normalizedFunctionName}EventsRuleSchedule{SequentialID}
      Type: AWS::Events::Rule
      Properties:
        Targets:
          - Id: "anyId"
```

Here is a guide to modify a Cloudformation resource.
https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/resources#override-aws-cloudformation-resource

Answer (score 0):

Then you need to describe your schedule rule as the separate resource in *serverless.yaml* file.

For example:

```
ScheduledRule: 
  Type: AWS::Events::Rule
  Properties: 
    Description: "ScheduledRule"
    ScheduleExpression: "rate(10 minutes)"
    State: "ENABLED"
    Targets: 
      - 
        Arn: 
          Fn::GetAtt: 
            - "LambdaFunction"
            - "Arn"
        Id: "TargetFunctionV1"
```

[AWS::Events::Rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-events-rule.html)

Comment: I tried this but an error. I actually found the solution. Solution is in the next comment

Comment: BTW: In your new comment - the script will create 2 rules.
I had a generic example how to create the event rule